# How to retrieve the last page number with soup in python

Tags: beautifulsoup

I wonder what is the best **soup** way to retrieve the last page's number from a piece of "**li**" tags, here is an example:

```
                <li class="active">
    <span>1</span>
  </li>

                <li>
    <a href="https://www.test.com/page=2">2</a>
  </li>

                <li>
    <a href="https://www.test.com/page=3">3</a>
  </li>

                <li>
    <a href="https://www.test.com/page=4">4</a>
  </li>


                <li class="pages disabled">
    <span>&hellip;</span>
  </li>

      <li class="next">
  <a href="https://www.test.com/page=2">
    <i class="icon-chevron-right"


  ></i>
  </a>
</li>

        <li>
      <a href="https://www.test.com/page=30">Last</a>
  </li>
```

In this case, I need to get the last page number of **"30"**

Thank you very much. Similar questions are seen on SO but do not apply to my case.

UPDATE:

Thanks to Bitto's answer.

The above HTML source was actually **not accurate** as they were manually copied from source of the page, what is used in my current code is something with soup and a ResultSet is generated as below:

Code:

```
source = requests.get(url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(source,features="html.parser").findAll("li")
```

[image]

Comment: You need to get the structure step by step until you get your anchor tag (<a href>) and then get the attribute with beautfiulsoup. A little observation I made when I used beautifulsoup few years ago is you can't use complex selector like JQuery in Javascript.  You have to do it step by step as I mentioned above (Maybe I'm wrong and I missused it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the `a` tag with the text `'Last'` and then get the page number from the `href` attribute.

```
html="""
<li class="active"><span>1</span></li>
<li><a href="https://www.test.com/page=2">2</a></li>
<li><a href="https://www.test.com/page=3">3</a></li>
<li><a href="https://www.test.com/page=4">4</a></li>
<li class="pages disabled"><span>&hellip;</span></li>
<li class="next"><a href="https://www.test.com/page=2"><i class="icon-chevron-right"></i></a></li>
<li><a href="https://www.test.com/page=30">Last</a></li>
"""
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup=BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
a=soup.find('a',text='Last')
last_page=a['href'].split('=')[1]
print(last_page)
```

Output

```
30
```

Comment: Thank you very much Bitto, turned out something missing here, please see my updated OP. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured out the solution now:

```
source = requests.get(url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(source,features="html.parser").findAll("li")
s = str(soup) 
page_info = BeautifulSoup(s[1:len(s)-1]) 
a=page_info.find('a',text='Last') 
last_page=a['href'].split('=')[-1]
```

Thank you @Bitto.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `:contains` psuedo class to ensure `Last` is in textcontent and an attribute = value selector to ensure `page=` is in the link

```
#html = your html
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
link = soup.select_one('[href*="page="]:contains(Last)')['href']
page = link.split('=')[1]
print(page, link)
```

Comment: Thank you for your input. appreciated here.

Comment: you are most welcome. Thank you for taking the time to respond :-)